# How to resolve 'Static DateFormatter objects should be accessed in a synchronized manner' in PMD

Tags: java

I am getting information like "Static DateFormatter objects should be accessed in a synchronized 
 manner" when I call DATEFORMATTER object.

```
class A{
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATEFORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss");
    JSONObject getJSON() {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("date",DATEFORMATTER.format(passing date object here));
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2409693/581414

Comment: also see [ThreadLocal SimpleDateFormat in an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27065455/217324)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SimpleDateFormat](http://Date%20formats%20are%20not%20synchronized.%20It%20is%20recommended%20to%20create%20separate%20format%20instances%20for%20each%20thread.%20If%20multiple%20threads%20access%20a%20format%20concurrently,%20it%20must%20be%20synchronized%20externally.)

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Rather creating DateFomate as static you can create in inside your function like:

```
class A{

    JSONObject getJSON() {
        SimpleDateFormat DATEFORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("date",DATEFORMATTER.format(passing date object here));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also consider using of `ThreadLocal` to avoid unnecessary object creation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)